# How can I find substring in a vector in c++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I want to know how can I find number of time a substring occured in vector which contains lines(group of string).

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

```
std::vector<std::string> v { "this is a line", "foo", "This is another line" };

auto count = std::count_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](auto const& s) {
  return s.find("line") != std::string::npos;
});

std::cout << count;
```

Comment: What can I do if I have to make whole this like a function.\

Comment: Where parameter of the function would be a vector and a substring.

Comment: `int func(std::vector<std::string>& v, std::string const& sub)` replace "line" with `sub` and `return count` should do it.

Comment: int count_occurance(std::vector<std::string>& v, std::string const& sub)
{
    // std::vector<std::string> v ;

auto count = std::count_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](auto const& s) {
  return s.find(sub) != std::string::npos;
});

// std::cout << count <<endl;
    return count;
}